# Touchscreen sensitivity

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an android app only for **tablets**, which will draw the lines as and where the user touches the screen. It is very simple and there are lot more apps like this. I have a doubt regarding the touch-screen technology. Is there any possibility that if the user touch the screen **soft** then the lines will be dull and if the user touch the screen **harder** then the lines drawn will be thicker? Is it even possible to do such things in tablet? I don't have info about the hardware and technology used in tablets, please guide me with a valid answers and please refer me to any blogs or docs which says about the touch sense technology.
    Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the OnTouch() Input Event (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) which is triggered when you touch the screen. So inside the VIEW in your application you should register an OnTouchListener using setOnTouchListener ([setOnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnTouchListener%28android.view.View.OnTouchListener%29)) with a callback to the function that will handle the event.

Inside your callback get the pressure properties:

> public float pressure
>
> Added in API level 9 A normalized value that describes the pressure
>   applied to the device by a finger or other tool. The pressure
>   generally ranges from 0 (no pressure at all) to 1 (normal pressure),
>   although values higher than 1 may be generated depending on the
>   calibration of the input device.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.PointerCoords.html#pressure

When you touch the screen you get  a MotionEvent which has many methods and one of them gives you the pressure

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

> final float    getPressure() getPressure(int)
>
> final float getPressure(int pointerIndex)

Comment: Thanks fersarr,
From this I can actually control the input according to the sense?, I mean is it possible to do the task which I have mentioned above?

Comment: Thanks fersarr, that was usefull